Article in Soviet Journal of Nuclear Physics
How can I find an old paper from Soviet journal of Nuclear Physics
B. G. Zakharov, Yad. Fiz. 49. 1386 (1989) [Sov. J. Nucl. Phys. 49, 860 (1989)],
in Russian or in English?
This volume is abs of Sov.J.Nucl Phys is absent in our University Library.
Please could you advise?

All I could find was the title of the paper and its abstract. And generally, for Soviet journals it seems virtually impossible to find an electronic copy of almost any paper. A working method that I successfully used was to go to a library and get access to the physical copy of the journal. Particularly, I did this in the National Library of Russia in Saint-Petersburg. Maybe there are similar publicly accessible libraries in other countries.

Ask your friendly local research librarian.

Your local research librarian may be able to get you a copy via interlibrary loan.

Maybe z-library?
